# Unable to run spark-submit command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, sbt, sbt-assembly

Hi I am a newbie to Spark and Scala.
Been trying to run a sbt compiled uber jar file using spark-submit.

```
  package com.spark.scala

    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.log4j._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem 
    import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider
    import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider._
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem

    /** Compute the average number of friends by age in a social network. */
    object AwsSample {


      /** Our main function where the action happens */
      def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AwsSample")
        new SparkConf().setAppName("AwsSample")  //.setMaster("spark://**.**.**.**:7077")

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


        System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

        val keyId = "**********"
        val accessKey = "****************"
        val endPoint= "s3.*some-region*.amazonaws.com"

        val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration

        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", keyId)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", keyId)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", keyId)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", accessKey)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", accessKey)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", accessKey)
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", endPoint)

        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

        var poll = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3a://**/***/**/**.snappy")

        println(poll.count())

      } 
    }
```

I am using this command to execute the sbt jar file, once packages and assebly is done...

```
spark-submit --class com.spark.scala.AwsSample --master 
spark://****:**** --deploy-mode cluster awssample_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Running it locally is a no sweat. It works fine.. The error is when I try running it on the cluster like in the code.. This is the Error I am facing

```
        Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
        Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestProtocolException: Malformed response received from server
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.org$apache$spark$deploy$rest$RestSubmissionClient$$postJson(RestSubmissionClient.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$createSubmission$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$createSubmission$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:86)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.createSubmission(RestSubmissionClient.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClientApp.run(RestSubmissionClient.scala:429)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClientApp.start(RestSubmissionClient.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
        Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
        at [Source: <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
        </head>
        <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /v1/submissions/create. Reason:
        <pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

        </body>
        </html>
        ; line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:462)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1624)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:689)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3776)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3721)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$class.parse(JsonMethods.scala:20)
        at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(JsonMethods.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestProtocolMessage$.parseAction(SubmitRestProtocolMessage.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestProtocolMessage$.fromJson(SubmitRestProtocolMessage.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$1.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$1.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:235)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: you are getting a 404. Be sure the master´s url is correct...

Comment: also looks like the error code and HTTP content type isn't being checked in the Spark code. Not ideal, but I've seen worse: at least Spark prints the text it couldn't handle